# How do impurities affect the surface tension of fluids?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension

I want to know what happens to the surface tension of fluids if we add impurities and the reason behind it.

Comment: are you referring to impurities in the bulk material or on the surface exclusively?

Comment: That's a bit vague. What kind of impurities? What kind of fluids?